# Can a 3rd disconnected ADO recordset be calculated from two source disconnected ADO recordsets?

Tags: vba, ms-access, com, oledb, ado

This is for use in Excel VBA, so COM experts and MS Access experts most welcome.

ADO is the object model for OLEDB.  OLEDB was promised as universal access.  Just as ODBC standardised access to previously disparate relational databases, OLEDB was to standardise access to even more disparate data sources such as databases, emails, file systems etc.

To me, the concept of universal data access implies that a disconnected recordset could also be one of those disparate OLEDB data sources.

Can a disconnected recordset purely in-memory be a source for a query?

The critical use case would be to take two (tabular) in-memory disconnected recordsets sources and run a SQL join on both to derive a third in-memory disconnected recordset.  (There is no intention of writing the results back to any database of origin.)

Is this possible?  Would I have to write my own OLEDB provider to do so?  StackOverflow previously helped me to [compile a OLEDB Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217627/oledb-c-atls-oledb-provider-sample-crashes-excel-uncaught-exception-from) so I know there is great expertise on this site.

Comment: I know you can create a new recordset and populate it piece-by-piece with data of your choosing. So having VBA functions do the join should be possible (don't know about the performance though). From a quick google/stack search, querying recordsets directly doesn't seem to be possible. If you need to use SQL, the closest thing would be to dump the data in recordset 1 and 2 into temporary tables (Excel or Access) and then query those. Not sure if you could build those tables only in memory as well...?

Comment: @Inarion : I'm aware one can write to Excel worksheet and Access temporary table, thanks.  Looking for a purely in memory solution.  I have edited question text to stress this, thanks.

Comment: No, a recordset can't be the source of a query (there is no database engine behind to perform a "query"). To fill the third recordset, you will have to loop and search both existing recordsets to simulate a "join" and fill the "matching" rows one-by-one into the third recordset.